# Using enums at angular material select, but I it does not work

Tags: angular, enums, angular-material, material-ui, frontend

**This is my ts file**

> I want to create a select list with enums But I
> am getting Error. I shared screenshots, I see enums with their keys and values, I want to see their keys only, and ı want to save their values via form

```
export class AddCenterComponent implements OnInit {


  CenterTypes = CenterType;
  enumKeys = [];


  addCenterForm = new FormGroup({
    centerType: new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),
    tel: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]),
  });

  clearForm() {
    this.addCenterForm.patchValue({
      centerType: '',
      tel: '',
    });
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.enumKeys = Object.keys(this.CenterTypes);
  }

  getErrorMessage(element: string) {

   
    if (element == "centerType") {
      if (this.addCenterForm.get('centerType').hasError('required')) {
        return 'Merkez tipi giriniz';
      }
    }
   

    if (element == "tel") {
      if (this.addCenterForm.get('tel').hasError('required')) {
        return 'telefon giriniz';
      }
    return "";
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**this is my cshtml file**

```
                              <mat-form-field appearance="outline"   style="font-size: 11px;">
                                <mat-label>Merkez Tipi</mat-label>
                                  <mat-select formControlName="centerType" >
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let name of enumKeys" [value] = CenterTypes[key]>
                                      {{CenterTypes[name]}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                  </mat-select>
                                <mat-error *ngIf="addCenterForm.get('centerType').errors"> {{ getErrorMessage("centerType") }}  </mat-error>
                              </mat-form-field>
```

**and this is my enum file**

```
export enum CenterType
{
    HeadOffice = 1,
    HeadOfficePool = 2
}
```

[image: enums come with their values, I want only keys here]

[image: after I select, key does not set in dropdown here]

Answer (score 0):

Try to get **Key-Value** Pair of enums.

```
this.enumKeys =  = Object.entries(this.CenterTypes).map(([key, value]) => ({ name:key,value:value }));
```

and in your **html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="font-size: 11px;">
<mat-label>Merkez Tipi</mat-label>
<mat-select formControlName="centerType">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let enum of enumKeys" [value]="enum.value">
        {{enum.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
<mat-error *ngIf="addCenterForm.get('centerType').errors"> {{ getErrorMessage("centerType") }} </mat-error>
```

Comment: this.enumKeys contain 4 element, they have 
name: '1', value : 'HeadOffice'
name: '2', value : 'HeadOfficePool'
name: 'HeadOffice', value : '1'
name: 'HeadOfficePool', value : '2'  , but I want to only 2 element in array.